# Select subcollection in one query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

We have 2 tables

```
users
id|name|age
1|John|20
2|Bill|22

user_roles
id|user_id|role
1|1|moderator
2|1|admin
3|2|moderator
```

How to select all users, where age> 18 and age < 30, with all their roles in one query? Without duplication of users information

Result should have 2 rows

- info about user with id 1 and his roles
- info about user with id 2 and his roles

Comment: Hint: use `INNER JOIN` between `users` and `user_roles` and `ON` `users.id=user_roles.userid` and use `WHERE` on `age`.

Comment: It will extract without duplication of users information?

Comment: Could you provide sample and desired output?

Comment: Can you check please one more time?

Comment: @clement answer is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a left outer join and aggregate the roles with `ARRAY_AGG`:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.age, ARRAY_AGG(r.role) 
FROM users u LEFT OUTER JOIN user_roles r ON u.id = r.user_id 
WHERE age BETWEEN 19 AND 29 
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, u.age
```

If you want a separate row for each role try:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.age, r.role
FROM users u LEFT OUTER JOIN user_roles r ON u.id = r.user_id 
WHERE age BETWEEN 19 AND 29
```